# Is it possible to add selectionCounter to PrimeFaces components?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have a selectManyMenu (PF 6.2) and I defined this new property:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.prototype.selectionCounter = null;
```

and increment and decrement It in extended prototype functions for `Select All` and `Unselect All` buttons, in order to set the `selectionCounter` as value of another component. This works. But the problem is, the counter must be also updated if user selects items without using these buttons, by simply clicking on items. I tried to "override" `selectItem(item)` & `unselect(item)` methods like this

```javascript
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.prototype.selectItem() = function () {   <!--Parameter "item" ??-->

   this.selectItem(item);    
   this.selectionCounter++; 
}
```

and

```javascript
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.prototype.unselectItem() = function () {   <!--Parameter "item" ??-->

   this.unselectItem(item);    
   this.selectionCounter--;
}
```

but -not surprisingly- I can't pass a valid `item` parameter to them and get *"Invalid left-hand side of the assignment"* error at the function signature. I can't make use of `change` event either because it need to know if it is a selection or unselection.
 
Has anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes remove the parenthesis the way to override a method is like this.

```javascript
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.prototype.selectItem = function(item) {
  item.addClass('ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
  this.options.eq(item.index()).prop('selected', true);

   if(this.cfg.showCheckbox) {
            this.selectCheckbox(item.find('div.ui-chkbox-box'));
   }
   this.selectionCounter++; 
}
```

and

```javascript
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.prototype.unselectItem = function(item) {
   item.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
        this.options.eq(item.index()).prop('selected', false);

   if(this.cfg.showCheckbox) {
      this.unselectCheckbox(item.find('div.ui-chkbox-box'));
   }
   this.selectionCounter--;
}
```

Comment: I get an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at c.PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.selectItem`. To avoid recursivity, I can use another method name for selections via buttons but click-selection won't update the counter then :/

Comment: I edited my answer. Just cut and paste the above methods and it will work.

Comment: Thany you, but now i get `jsFile.js.faces:5 Uncaught TypeError: this._super is not a function
    at c.PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.selectItem` error

Comment: OK I updated my ansswer again and tested it in the Showcase and its working great!